# JavaScript loop through object to append arrays to arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I spent all night working on this, and I know the answer is close; but I still have a lot of syntax work to do. Please do not downvote this - doing so only discourages newbies like me from asking questions. 
I need to create a function that accepts simple objects as an argument, and returns an array of arrays. Function should work on objects with any number of columns of properties with a simple string/number value. I'll show and explain my work in the codes I'll attach below:

```js
//my first code:
var hi = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var props = new Array([],[],[]);
var lent = 0;
function newWave(hi){
  for(var key in hi){
    props[lent].push(key);
    props[lent].push(hi[key]);
    lent = lent + 1;
  }
  return props;
}
newWave(hi);

//function yields: [ [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ] ]
//The return output is correct, but I need a universal code; 
//looking at the number of columns in variable 'props', you can 
//tell that this function only works on objects with 3 roperties.
```

```js
//My second code:
function newWave(hi) {
  var props = [];
  var outcome = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<1; i++){
    for(var key in hi){
      props.push(key, hi[key]);
      outcome.push(props);
    }
    return outcome;
  }
}
newWave(hi);
//This returns:
//[ [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ],
//  [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ],
//  [ 'a', 1 ], [ 'b', 2 ], [ 'c', 3 ] ]
//I feel like the answer is so close, but it's been 7 hours working on this,
//your help is greatly appreciated
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function newWave (hi) {
    return Object.keys(hi).map(v => [v, hi[v]]);
}
```

So here we use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the object properties, and then for each of those we map them to an array thay has the property as first item and its value as second

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define array before, you can just create new empty array in your function, loop passed object and push `[key, value]`

```js
var hi = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

function newWave(obj) {
  var r = []
  for (var key in obj) r.push([key, obj[key]])
  return r;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(newWave(hi)))
```

Also there is new js method called [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)  that can return this result.

```js
var hi = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

function newWave(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj)
}

console.log(newWave(hi))
```

Comment: Didn´t know about entries method, nice

Comment: Excellent shortcut, but for this assignment, 'return' is required, not console.log. And it had to be in the conventional outline of a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys` to get all the keys present in the Object in an array. Loop over that array and push the keys and value to another array

```js
var hi = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4
};
var finalArray = []

function newWave(hi) {
  var getKeys = Object.keys(hi);
  for (var i = 0; i < getKeys.length; i++) {
    var tempArray = [];
    tempArray.push(getKeys[i].toString(), hi[getKeys[i]])
    finalArray.push(tempArray)
  }
  return finalArray;
}

console.log(newWave(hi));
```